# In AngularJS, how do you specify secondary sort?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

The code below is adapted from the AngularJS tutorial step 4 (http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04)

I'm able to specify the secondary sort in the controller.js code using an Array.  It works great on load.

The template, I believe, is where the problem is.  I can't figure out how set an Array that Angular will recognize properly for the filter.  As mentioned, the primary and secondary sorts work fine on load.  However when you look at the combo-box it incorrectly has a third option, and when you change the Order By combo-box to 'Newest' the resulting sort is wrong.

Here's a JSfiddle showing the problem (see line 8 of the HTML, and line 26 of the Javascript):
http://jsfiddle.net/M6JLe/6/

If you'd prefer to view code, here it is:

```
<!-- template -->
<div ng-app='phonecatApp'>
    <div ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
        Search: <input ng-model="query"><br />
        OrderProp: {{orderProp}}<br />
        Sort by: 
       <select ng-model="orderProp">
          <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
          <option value="['age','name']">Newest</option>
       </select>

       <br />

       <ul class="phones">
          <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
            {{phone.name}}
            <p>{{phone.snippet}} ({{phone.age}})</p>
          </li>
       </ul>



// Javascript
    'use strict';

    /* Controllers */

    var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

    phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.phones = [
        {'name': 'Nexus S',
         'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
         'age': 4},
        {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
         'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
         'age': 2},
        {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™',
         'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
         'age': 3},
        {'name': 'Apple iPhone 5s',
         'snippet': 'Apple\'s newest smartphone',
         'age': 3},
        {'name': 'ABC Phone X',
         'snippet': 'Some text snippet',
         'age': 3}
      ];

      $scope.orderProp = ['age','name'];
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've already realized, the problem is that the select options are strings, while you're using orderProp as an array. One way you could make this work (not necessarily the best):

Modification to your HTML:

```
<select ng-model="orderProp">
    <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
    <option value="age,name">Newest</option>
</select>
<br />
<ul class="phones">
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:getOrder()">{{phone.name}}
        <p>{{phone.snippet}} ({{phone.age}})</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Modification to your controller:

```
$scope.orderProp = "age,name";
$scope.getOrder = function () {
    var tokens = $scope.orderProp.split(",");
    var order = [];
    tokens.forEach(function (token) {
        order.push(token.toString());
    });

    return order;
};
```

See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/3kXLS/).

Comment: Yeah.  Your answer has a cleaner approach than my solution.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by using AngularJS's OrderBy function capability.  Please see the JSFiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/M6JLe/8/

Basically in the template I removed the Array field list and went with strings to represent the sorting I wanted to do (see below):

```
<select ng-model="orderProp">
      <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
      <option value="age_name">Age then Name</option>
      <option value="age">Newest</option>
      <option value="-age">Oldest</option>
</select>
```

Then on the ng-repeat I pointed the filter OrderBy to a custom function in the controller:

```
<ul class="phones">
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:customOrderBy">
        {{phone.name}}
        <p>{{phone.snippet}} ({{phone.age}})</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the controller modifications:

```
$scope.orderProp = 'age_name';
$scope.customOrderBy = function(phone) {
  switch($scope.orderProp) {
     case 'age_name':
         return (phone.age < 100 ? (phone.age < 10 ? '00' + phone.age : '0' + phone.age) : phone.age) + ' ' + phone.name;
         break;
     case 'age':
         return phone.age;
         break;
     case '-age':
         return -phone.age;
         break;
     default:
         return phone.name;
         break;
  }
};
```

It works.  But a few things I don't like are...

1. It will only sort by age and name if the age is less than 999.  Blech!
2. The array method as opposed to the function method is better for sorting against multiple fields and works great, but specifying the array as a string value in the template's select/option html seems to trip up AngularJS.  In my opinion this is just a tad bit broken unless there's a way to specify the select/option value in such a way that AngularJS can parse out the array properly.  Sadly, I wasn't able to figure it out.

For now, I think this solution will have to do.